# where I should print my results

Tags: printing, coding-style

I'm talking about good practies, expetially in C/C++ or Python field ( but my question is not based on a specific programming language).
When I want to print a result, where I should put my `printf` or `cout` or `print`?
If this result is computed by a function and then it is returned to main, I should print it in the main or not?
Should the main be free from console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this result is computed by a function and then it is returned to
>   main, I should print it in the main or not?

Yes, print it on main. In your case I think you can just do the print of the function like: `print(functionWithReturnType());`
You can also define a variable equal to the function type, and define it equal to the value that the function return, in case you want to use that value more than once.

> Should the main be free from console output?

No. You should allways put the console output in main.